# asp.net - sqlexception was unhandled by user code in

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I searched alot about this error on stackoverflow, but those problems were far from my error subject...

I'm programming a CMS with "Tuts+" tutorials and I'm getting this code each time I tried to resolve it...
error:

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)
>   I tried for restart sql services and turn off firewall and... but!...
>       and the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using WebMatrix.Data;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for PostHandler
/// </summary>
public class PostHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public PostHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var title = context.Request.Form["postTitle"];
        var content = context.Request.Form["postContent"];
        var slug = CreateSlug(title);


        using (var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection"))

        {

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Slug = @0";

            var result = db.QuerySingle(sql, slug);




            if (result != null) {

                throw new HttpException(409, "SLUG IS ALREADY IN USE!");

            }

            sql = "INSERT INTO Posts (Title, Content, AuthorId, Slug" +
                    "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)";
            db.Execute(sql, title, content, 1, slug);
        }
    }


    private static string CreateSlug(String title)
    {
        title = title.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" ", "-");
        title = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^0-9a-z-]", string.Empty);

        return title;
    } 
}
```

I got this error on line:

`var result = db.QuerySingle(sql, slug);`

Comment: This error means your connection string is wrong. It is stored in web.config. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for how to put together a connection string. There is no universal methodology for troubleshooting a defective connection string

Answer (score -1):

Go to control panel/search for services find the SQL Server(XXX) service, and check if it is Running. If it is not running then Start it and try to login in SSMS again.

Read more [Here](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html) with image illustration